# How do I block unknown calls to my sites?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have some security issue with my website. It started by creating wp-admin directory on my FTP server with malicioust .txt file. index.php was also changed (some code at the beginning was added)

I changed all passwords and completely deleted the CMS folder from the server. I removed also wp-admin directory and malicious code from index.php

Lots of unauthorized connections to my website started with this change.

**Detalis here:**
[database log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xs5c.jpg)

All calls to .shtml files were blocked by .htaccess file.
Unfortunately there are still attempts to access other resources

**for example:**

- /wp-load.php?daksldlkdsadas&
- /ajax-index.php?url=http://domainnamespace.top/lf.jpeg
- /aindex.php?daksldlkdsadas&
- /wp-load.php?WordPress=newzealandpolicy.wang/popn.txt&Database=1index.php
- /sitemapimages79.xml
- /sitemapimages5.xml

**How can i prevent this calls?**
**What kind of attack is it and what is its purpose?**

**It's not wordpress based website**

Comment: Welcome to the internet. These calls are just bots trying to break your security through known vulnerabilities.You can try to use a DDOS protection (like cloudflare) against it or blacklist their IPs  but there is no 100% reliable method.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not wordpress based website. Although these files (*.shtml) do not exist (404), the pages have been indexed on Google. How is this possible?

Comment: Maybe they were present at some time.
Google Search indexes are not updated in real time.

Comment: There isn’t much you actually _need_ to do. You can not prevent people/bots from _making_ these requests, at most you could try and identify them, and respond with a 403 Forbidden or something like that. But if your site is not even a WP site, there is rather little point in that. The situation you have here, is that people from the other side of the street are shouting “Hey Paul, you ***!” over to your side. Sure, anyone actually named Paul could be affected by that. But your name is not even Paul, so … why bother?

Comment: What kind of attack is it and what is its purpose? How this files was created? (I checked all server logs and there was not direct FTP access ). Instruction like 'exec' are disabled. I found some topics about SSI (Server Side Includes). I tried to "attack" my site with popular instructions (from web), but was unable to create any directory.

Comment: You can try block it using 1. mod_security (apache, nginx, OLS), 2. fail2ban (by adding some regex on and add it to apache), 3. Just block the IP. In you conversation, I think the right choice is mod_security, but it's not 100% bulletproof, at least script kiddie won't able to go through. Or Last Using Web Application Firewall on WP. Remember, PHP enterprise community hates Wordpress, a lot (Even I use it myself, I got a lot of rant from many enteprise community about WP bad design)

Comment: @Benyamin Limanto - i'll try this. Thanks. BTW: It's not wordpress based website. It's page based on my own CMS :)

Comment: Oh I heard it's not wordpress based site, what a troublesome. I think this question should be asked on security StackExchange or ServerFault. If you are a sysadmin, then come to chat with us (CentOS, Ubuntu-Server, and Fail2ban community) on Freenode. Many of them have a trick under their sleeve, Gud Luck